# Boundless Numbers in C#

Tags: c#

A short has 16 bits.

An int 32.

A long 64.

Is there any way to represent a boundless integer in C#?  By boundless I mean something that is arbitrarily large and would be limited by the memory that you have.

Comment: There are always bounds imposed by your memory size.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'boundless'? If you mean 'infinite', then no - inherently memory is finite, and even if you had a $VERY_BIG_MEMORY filled with a single stream of bits representing an integer, it is still ultimately finite and therefore has a maximum value which can be represented.

Comment: Oh, that much I appreciate.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question by specifying what you mean by 'boundless'?

Comment: Much better - now the BigInt structure answer below has relevance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) struct.

Comment: This isn't boundless - it is bound by memory. It merely has no fixed bound imposed by the structure. "Because the BigInteger type is immutable (see Mutability and the BigInteger Structure) and because it has no upper or lower bounds, an OutOfMemoryException can be thrown for any operation that causes a BigInteger value to grow too large."

Comment: @Jonners It’s still the closest you can get to “boundless”.

Comment: @poke In the context of the original question (pre-edit) there was no explicit definition of 'boundless', which meant that memory was the implicit upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

Try [IntX](https://github.com/devoyster/IntXLib).

> IntX is an arbitrary precision integers library written in pure C# 2.0 with fast -- about O(N * log N) -- multiplication/division algorithms implementation. It provides all the basic arithmetic operations on integers, comparing, bitwise shifting etc. It also allows parsing numbers in different bases and converting them to string, also in any base. The advantage of this library is fast multiplication, division and from base/to base conversion algorithms -- all the fast versions of the algorithms are based on fast multiplication of big integers using Fast Hartley Transform which runs for O(N * log N * log log N) time instead of classic O(N^2).